# Serialize data before inserting into the DB

Tags: database

I need to store some post IDs in the DB in a custom table/field. The IDs will have to be stored in a serialized format. I know that, ie. for the options, serialization is done automatically for add/update functions (`add_option()`, `update_option()`). Is there a built-in WP function to serialize data for any other case? Or should I just use `serialize()`? Similarly, as soon as the data will be retrieved, is there a stock WP function to unserialize it, or will I have to use `unserialize()`? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP functions...

Serialize: [maybe_serialze](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/)

Unserialize: [maybe_unserialize](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/)

Comment: Thank you very much!